# Installing Basemap in virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib-basemap

I am using Python 3.6.9 and in a virtual environment and I am trying to install **basemap**, with no luck.

I have read over and over the installing [guidelines](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html) and other sources. But the basemap file is never created at directory of the virtual environment: `venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/`.

Any help would be appreciated. This is what I do

```
pip3 install --upgrade --user matplotlib numpy pyproj pyshp OWSLib Pillow
sudo apt install libgeos-dev
sudo apt-get install proj-bin
sudo apt-get install geos
wget https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/refs/tags/v1.2.2rel.tar.gz
untar
cd geos-3.3.3
export GEOS_DIR=/usr/local
./configure --prefix=$GEOS_DIR
make; make install
cd ..
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

Then the code output looks like this

```
checking for GEOS lib in /home/secure ....
checking for GEOS lib in /home/secure/local ....
checking for GEOS lib in /usr ....
GEOS lib (version 3.6.2) found in /usr
running install
/home/secure/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:37: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  setuptools.SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
/home/secure/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py:159: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  EasyInstallDeprecationWarning,
/home/secure/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:119: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: 0.18ubuntu0.18.04.1 is an invalid version and will not be supported in a future release
  PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning,
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
running build_src
build_src
building extension "_geoslib" sources
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
writing lib/basemap.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to lib/basemap.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing namespace_packages to lib/basemap.egg-info/namespace_packages.txt
writing requirements to lib/basemap.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to lib/basemap.egg-info/top_level.txt
/home/secure/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py:628: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: Custom 'build_py' does not implement 'get_data_files_without_manifest'.
Please extend command classes from setuptools instead of distutils.
  SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning
reading manifest file 'lib/basemap.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching 'README'
warning: no files found matching 'LICENSE_proj4'
warning: no files found matching 'LICENSE_pyshp'
warning: no files found matching 'lib/mpl_toolkits/basemap/pyproj.py'
warning: no files found matching 'lib/mpl_toolkits/basemap/shapefile.py'
adding license file 'LICENSE_data'
adding license file 'LICENSE_epsg'
adding license file 'LICENSE_geos'
writing manifest file 'lib/basemap.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
customize UnixCCompiler
customize UnixCCompiler using build_ext
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/_geoslib.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/countries_h.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/gshhs_i.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/lsmask_2.5min_c.bin -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/countriesmeta_h.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/riversmeta_f.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/gshhsmeta_l.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/statesmeta_c.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/lsmask_10min_i.bin -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/countriesmeta_f.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/lsmask_5min_i.bin -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/lsmask_10min_c.bin -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/states_l.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/countries_c.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/gshhsmeta_i.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/countriesmeta_l.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/epsg -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/riversmeta_i.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/rivers_h.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/lsmask_2.5min_l.bin -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/riversmeta_l.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/countriesmeta_i.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/bmng.jpg -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/lsmask_1.25min_i.bin -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/statesmeta_i.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/states_f.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/gshhsmeta_c.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/gshhs_f.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/gshhsmeta_h.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/lsmask_10min_f.bin -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/rivers_f.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/etopo1.jpg -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/UScounties.dbf -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/states_c.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/countries_f.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/lsmask_1.25min_f.bin -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/rivers_i.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/statesmeta_h.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/lsmask_5min_f.bin -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/states_i.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/lsmask_10min_h.bin -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/lsmask_1.25min_c.bin -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/lsmask_5min_l.bin -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/countries_l.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/gshhsmeta_f.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/countries_i.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/lsmask_5min_h.bin -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/statesmeta_l.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/riversmeta_h.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/rivers_c.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/UScounties.prj -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/lsmask_2.5min_i.bin -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/lsmask_2.5min_f.bin -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/countriesmeta_c.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/states_h.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/lsmask_1.25min_l.bin -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/riversmeta_c.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/lsmask_5min_c.bin -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/lsmask_2.5min_h.bin -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/gshhs_c.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/shadedrelief.jpg -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/rivers_l.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/lsmask_1.25min_h.bin -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/statesmeta_f.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/lsmask_10min_l.bin -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/UScounties.shx -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/gshhs_l.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/UScounties.shp -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/gshhs_h.dat -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/diagnostic.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/proj.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/solar.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/cm.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mpl_toolkits/basemap/test.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/__init__.py to __init__.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/diagnostic.py to diagnostic.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/proj.py to proj.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/solar.py to solar.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py to __init__.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/cm.py to cm.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/test.py to test.cpython-36.pyc
creating stub loader for _geoslib.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/_geoslib.py to _geoslib.cpython-36.pyc
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying lib/basemap.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying lib/basemap.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying lib/basemap.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying lib/basemap.egg-info/namespace_packages.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying lib/basemap.egg-info/requires.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying lib/basemap.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
writing build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO/native_libs.txt
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
__pycache__._geoslib.cpython-36: module references __file__
mpl_toolkits.basemap.__pycache__.__init__.cpython-36: module references __file__
creating 'dist/basemap-1.2.1-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing basemap-1.2.1-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg
removing '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/basemap-1.2.1-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg' (and everything under it)
creating /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/basemap-1.2.1-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg
Extracting basemap-1.2.1-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg to /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
basemap 1.2.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/basemap-1.2.1-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg
Processing dependencies for basemap==1.2.1
Searching for six==1.12.0
Best match: six 1.12.0
Adding six 1.12.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using /home/secure/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Searching for pyshp==2.1.0
Best match: pyshp 2.1.0
Adding pyshp 2.1.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using /home/secure/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Searching for pyproj==2.5.0
Best match: pyproj 2.5.0
Adding pyproj 2.5.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using /home/secure/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Searching for numpy==1.16.6
Best match: numpy 1.16.6
Adding numpy 1.16.6 to easy-install.pth file
Installing f2py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing f2py3 script to /usr/local/bin
Installing f2py3.6 script to /usr/local/bin

Using /home/secure/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Searching for matplotlib==3.2.0
Best match: matplotlib 3.2.0
Adding matplotlib 3.2.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using /home/secure/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Searching for kiwisolver==1.1.0
Best match: kiwisolver 1.1.0
Adding kiwisolver 1.1.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using /home/secure/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Searching for python-dateutil==2.8.0
Best match: python-dateutil 2.8.0
Adding python-dateutil 2.8.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using /home/secure/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Searching for cycler==0.10.0
Best match: cycler 0.10.0
Adding cycler 0.10.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
Searching for pyparsing==2.4.0
Best match: pyparsing 2.4.0
Adding pyparsing 2.4.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using /home/secure/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Searching for setuptools==59.5.0
Best match: setuptools 59.5.0
Adding setuptools 59.5.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using /home/secure/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Finished processing dependencies for basemap==1.2.1
```

Comment: Do you have your venv activated?

Comment: Yes, I did source `venv/bin/activate`, and it shows on the right (venv)

Comment: As @askman says you need to activate the virtual environment before you start. Also, you need to remove the `--user` from the first line or otherwise you get the error `ERROR: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.` The fact that you didn't see this error indicates that your virtual environment was not activated correctly.